# Copying Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, cryptography, copy, byte

I'm experimenting with AES encryption. However, I get an error I wrote from the following code:

```
private static byte[] readKey(String request) throws KeyFileNotFoundException,
 UnsupportedEncodingException, UnknownKeyException {

    File keyFile = new File(Logging.getCurrentDir() + "\\cikey.key");
    Properties keys = new Properties();
    byte[] storage;

    if (!keyFile.exists())
        throw new KeyFileNotFoundException("Key file not located.");

    if (keys.containsKey(request) == false)
        throw new UnknownKeyException("Key not found."); //I RECIEVE THIS ERROR

    storage = keys.getProperty(request).getBytes(); //read the STRING value and turn into a byte array

    return storage;
}
```

This is the code from the method calling `readKey()`. I also am having problems **copying** the byte array read in through the `readKey()` method to the `decrypt()` method. Please read the comments in the methods for more detailed explanations.

```
public static String decrypt(String in) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
  NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
  IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException,
  KeyFileNotFoundException, UnknownKeyException {

    String out = " "; //decrypted String to return

    byte[] key = readKey("key").clone(); //my attempt to copy a byte array
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    byte iv[] = readKey("iv"); //works here? same as above so I don't know.
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    //initialize the cipher for decryption
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);

    // decrypt the message
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(in.getBytes());

    out = asHex(decrypted);

    return out;
}
```

Any ideas to fixing this problem?

Comment: You don't appear to be reading the contents of keyFile into the Properties object.

Comment: clone() is a perfectly valid way to copy an array. However, I can't see why you'd need to copy arrays in this case. Also, using the key as the IV can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the `keys` variable using one of [`Properties.load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) methods before checking for a key.

Additionally you can clone the array using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int%29), the clone method or [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5b%5d,int,int%29)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice I hadn't loaded it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy arrays.

**EDIT**

Another option is to use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29) although that just uses `System.arrayCopy()` under the hood.

Comment: just to addup the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int))

Comment: @SrinathGanesh thanks for the javadoc link.  I actually included that in my original answer, but I guess the links don't show up well when they are tied to text which is formatted as code.

Comment: my above link too got messed up . the '(' in link kills the link

Answer (score 2):

You are not initialize Property with values in the file so keys is empty and when you are calling keys.contains("") its returning false you have write 
InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(keyFile);
 keys.load(stream);

after property keys=new Property();
in readKey() method then you will get 
a byte array if you will try to find a 
valid key.